# Is an upgrade to Etihad's business class worth 1500 CAD?

Tags: budget, price, upgrades

I am flying on Etihad from Toronto to India. I have booked a round trip for business class but due to less availability, I was only booked for business on my return flight and economy on my outgoing flight.

However, surprisingly I have received an e-mail from Etihad about an upgrade offer. Etihad has asked me to place an offer for how much I am willing to pay for an upgrade on my outgoing flight. The range of the offer is a minimum of $1500 (CAD) and goes up to $2500 (CAD).

At this moment, I honestly feel bad, I feel like it is a loss for me to offer such a high price for an upgrade offer. I was wondering if I should ignore the e-mail and request for an upgrade at the airport during check-in, would that be cheaper?

Comment: How much more would you have paid had you booked business class both ways in the first place?  How much would it cost you to change your booking right now (as it would seem they now have business class seats available on your outbound)?  How important is business class to you?  These are all things only you can weigh and then decide between.

Comment: It sounds like they are auctioning off upgrades. Waiting until check in means the auction will (probably) have completed, so unlikley to be cheaper.